# Simple Generic misunderstanding

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting, generic-constraints

Could you help me to understand the error in those case ?

```
public interface IGeneralInterface
{
}


public class A : IGeneralInterface
{
}

public class B : IGeneralInterface
{
}

public class SomeClass<TGenericType> where TGenericType : IGeneralInterface
{
    private TGenericType internalValue;

    public SomeClass(TGenericType InitValue)
    {
        internalValue = InitValue;
    }

    public TGenericType CreateAnother()
    {
       TGenericType val1 = new B();   //Error here: class B() could not be converted to TGenericType
       return val1;
    }
}
```

Even if I build the `SomeClass<T>` as

```
SomeClass<IGeneralInterface> someClass = new SomeClass<IGeneralInterface>();
```

I explicity pass base interface to include all (?) cases and it still throw an error

Comment: What if you've had `SomeClass<A> someA`? How can you return a `B` when `TGenericType` is `A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 TGenericType val1 = new B();   //Error here: class B() could not be converted to TGenericType
```

To

```
  IGeneralInterface val1 = new B();
```

You are trying to TypeCast `IGeneralInterface` to `TGenericType` which is the cause of error.

`TGenericType` could have other constraints, like it inherits from `ISpecificInterface` from which `B` donot inherit. In this case the assignment becomes invalid.

Example:

```
public class SomeClass< TGenericType> where TGenericType : IGeneralInterface, ISpecificInterface
TGenericType val1 = new B(); // TGenericType should be ISpecificInterface also, B is not.
```

For above to run. `IGenericInterface` should always be more specific than `TGenericType`.

```
 public class SomeClass <IGenericInterface>
```

Alternatively you could use `is` keyword to find out whether the object is assignable to `TGenericType` and then use the casting.

```
TGenericType val1 = default(TGenericType);
var val = new B();
if ( val is TGenericType)
{
  val1 = (TGenericType)val;
}
```

**EDIT** For the below comment

> how it could at runtime have additional requirements ? Everything I put in compiler listed here

`CreateAnother()` creates instance of Type `B` which is not generic.
Take below example

```
SomeClass<C> c = new SomeClass<C();
C another = c.CreateAnother(); // C is not assignable from B. (C is below). But It would be valid, if compiler did not flag the error

public class C : IGeneralInterface, IDisposable
{
}
```

Comment: You are trying to TypeCast IGeneralInterface to TGenericType which is the cause of error.  <-- yes. Why does it happens ? I explicity send IGeneralInterface as type for TGenericType

Comment: But `TGenericType` could also extend other interface, which `IGenericInterface` does not have

Comment: @Jasper:  No you did not.  You merely required that TGenericType implements the IGeneralInterface.  Since the TGenericType used at run-time may have additional requirements, your class has no way to know how to convert `B` into whatever type TGenericType may be invoked as.

Comment: @Tilak: You the first to answer - so thank you, but please try to stay in condition listed above. I do not add any another condition. Inheritance stay as they listed. Please do not add more conditions.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - how it could at runtime have additional requirements ? Everything I put in compiler listed here.

Comment: @Tilak Thank you for your time. I Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501439/generics-in-c-sharp-cannot-convert-classname-to-tgenericclass    (so the JeppeStigNilsen was the closes one) but you are the first to answer me. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think a `new B()` should be convertible to `TGenericType`? The only thing that is known about `TGenericType` is that it implements the interface.

As an example, `new B()` cannot be converted to type `A`.

I don't know what you are trying to obtain, but you could change the generic constraint to:

```
public class SomeClass<TGenericType>
    where TGenericType : class, IGeneralInterface, new()
```

Then it would be OK to say `new TGenericType()` inside your create method.

But the it would no longer be possible to use the type `SomeClass<IGeneralInterface>` because that interface does not have an accessible parameterless instance constructor (no interface can have constructors, of course).

Comment: As an example, new B() cannot be converted to type A. <-- it could via the interface that they both inherited from. Or at least they could be converted to base interface. And the base interface **it is** a type for generic class (TGenericType)

Comment: @Jasper It sounds like you're turning things the wrong way round. So-called transitivity means that if X converts to Y, and Y converts to Z, then X converts to Z. But you can't reverse the direction. You have: **`TGenericType` converts to `IGeneralInterface`** and **`B` converts to `IGeneralInterface`**. But both conversions go **towards** `IGeneralInterface`. So you can't use transitivity to conclude anything about `B` and `TGenericType` being interconvertible.

Comment: Thank you ! This was the part that I was missing. Thank you ! (Sorry - I already gave an 'answer' to Tilak because he/she was first)

Comment: (@Jasper It _is_ possible to change one's mind regarding which answer one marks as "accepted", so you could change it if you want, but it's also fine to reward quick answers.)

Comment: :) Tilko gave me a technical solution that is correct but you really understand the defect in my logic/thinking. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are declaring the variable

```
val1
```

of the type

```
TGenericType
```

and then you try to instantiate it by an object of a different type.

Even if you have stated the condition that the generic type of your class must be in the inheritance hierarchy of `IGeneralInterface` they are different for the compiler. I assume in this setting you would have to use an explicit cast.